# Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds - web scraping in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to recreate this worked example of webscraping data using R (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/exploring-h-1b-data-with-r#gs.V8vcRAc)

However, when I execute the line of code `all.h1b<-pblapply(all.urls, main)`
I progress to 90% and then get the error message:

Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Full code is this:

```
library(jsonlite)
   library(rvest)
   library(pbapply) 
   library(data.table)
json.cities<-paste0('http://h1bdata.info/cities.php?term=', letters)
all.cities<-unlist(pblapply(json.cities,fromJSON))
city.year<-expand.grid(city=all.cities,yr=seq(2012,2016))
##city.year$city<-urltools::url_encode(as.character(city.year$city))
city.year$city <- lapply(as.character(city.year$city), URLencode , reserved = TRUE)
all.urls<-paste0('http://h1bdata.info/index.php?em=&job=&city=', city.year[,1],'&year=', city.year[,2])
main<-function(url.x){
  x<-read_html(url.x)
  x<-html_table(x)
  x<-data.table(x[[1]])
  return(x)
  Sys.sleep(5)
}


##Sys.sleep(5)
all.h1b<-pblapply(all.urls, main)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you write the output of `class(x)` and `str(x)`?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm quite new to R so please bear with me. At what point do you want mew to use `class(x)' and `str(x)`

Comment: Write in R `class(x)` and `str(x)`, run the code and tell us which is the output.

Comment: `class(x)` 
[1] "numeric"
`str(x)`
 num [1:100] 0.597 -0.323 -0.199 0.47 -0.335 ...

Comment: Ok, so if `x` is numeric, you need to call it as `x[1]` instead of `x[[1]]` which should be the notation if it was a `list` rather than `numeric`

Comment: changing `x<-data.table(x[[1]])` to ` x<-data.table(x[1]) did result in the code working

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error appears when you try to access an array out of his boundary.
Sometimes this also happens when the package version is not up to date or is too up to date.
I'm trying the code too, let's see whether it works or if I have the same problem.

Try these changes

```
library(jsonlite)
   library(rvest)
   library(pbapply) 
   library(data.table)
json.cities<-paste0('http://h1bdata.info/cities.php?term=', letters)
all.cities<-unlist(pblapply(json.cities,fromJSON))
city.year<-expand.grid(city=all.cities,yr=seq(2012,2016))
city.year$city<-urltools::url_encode(as.character(city.year$city))
city.year$city <- lapply(as.character(city.year$city), URLencode , reserved = TRUE)
all.urls<-paste0('http://h1bdata.info/index.php?em=&job=&city=', city.year[,1],'&year=', city.year[,2])
main<-function(url.x){
  x<-read_html(url.x)
  x<-html_table(x)
  x<-data.table(x[1])
  return(x)
  Sys.sleep(5)
}

all.h1b<-pblapply(all.urls, main)
```

This code should work!